# XML ERROR "Invalid content was found starting with element"

Tags: xml, xml-schema

Me salen estos errores

> Error - Line 4, 8: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 8; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'phone'. One of '{sistema_operativo}' is expected.

> Error - Line 5, 6: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 6; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'nombre'. One of '{sistema_operativo}' is expected.

> Error - Line 33, 6: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 33; columnNumber: 6; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'nombre'. One of '{sistema_operativo}' is expected.

Aqui está el código XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<smartphone>
<phone>
<nombre>Xiaomi redmi 9</nombre>

<sistema_operativo>
<nombre>Android</nombre>
<version>10</version>
</sistema_operativo>

<Dimensiones>
<anchura>163.3</anchura>
<altura>77</altura>
<fondo>Verde</fondo>
</Dimensiones>

<Pes>198gr</Pes>

<Resolucion_de_pantalla>1080x2340</Resolucion_de_pantalla>

<Processador>OctaCore Mediatek Helio G80</Processador>

<Memoria>4.0GB</Memoria>

<Precio>159 euros</Precio>

</phone>



<phone>
<nombre>Xiaomi redmi 8</nombre>

<sistema_operativo>
<nombre>Android</nombre>
<version>7</version>
</sistema_operativo>

<Dimensiones>
<anchura>160</anchura>
<altura>68</altura>
<fondo>Vermell</fondo>
</Dimensiones>

<Peso>202gr</Peso>

<Resolucion_de_pantalla>1080x1920</Resolucion_de_pantalla>

<Processador>OctaCore Mediatek Helio G40</Processador>

<Memoria>2.0GB</Memoria>

<Precio>119 euros</Precio>

</phone>

</smartphone>
```

Y aquí el esquema XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:simpleType name="nombreType">
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
<!-- màximo de 40 caràcteres -->
<xs:minInclusive value="1" />
<xs:maxInclusive value="40"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="anchura" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="version" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="altura">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="fondo" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="peso" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Resolucion_de_pantalla"/>
<xs:element name="Processador" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Memoria" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Precio" type="xs:string"/>


<xs:element name="sistema_operativo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="nombre"/>
        <xs:element ref="version"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Dimensiones">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="anchura"/>
        <xs:element ref="altura"/>
        <xs:element ref="fondo"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="phone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="sistema_operativo"/>
        <xs:element ref="Dimensiones"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="smartphone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="sistema_operativo"/>
        <xs:element ref="Dimensiones"/>
        <xs:element ref="phone"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
    
</xs:schema>
```

¿Alguien sabe explicarme que significan los errores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que revisar la definición de tu XSD, pues la validación falla contra el XML de prueba que nos muestras.

El XML comienza por

```
<smartphone>
<phone>
<nombre>Xiaomi redmi 9</nombre>
...
```

Y en el XSD tienes

```
<xs:element name="phone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="sistema_operativo"/>
        <xs:element ref="Dimensiones"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="smartphone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="sistema_operativo"/>
        <xs:element ref="Dimensiones"/>
        <xs:element ref="phone"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Así pues, ese nombre que tienes al comienzo con un `phone` y el nombre del teléfono, no concuerda con la definición del elemento complejo smartphone, debería comenzar por un `sistema operativo`, que a su vez comienza por el nombre.

Así pues, si no me equivoco, cada uno de tus smartphone podría tener una estructura como esta si mantienes el XSD:

```
<smartphone>
  <sistema_operativo>
    <nombre>Android</nombre>
    <version>10</version>
  </sistema_operativo>
  <dimensiones>
    ...
  </dimensiones>
  <phone>
    <!-- acá se pone raro porque tienes OTRA VEZ sistema_operativo -->
  </phone>
</smartphone>
```

Lo otro es que revises cuál debe ser la estructura que valide el XSD. Probablemente quieres que exija algo diferente. Por lo que indicas en los comentarios, necesitas algo **similar a esto** (revísalo para que se ajuste a la estructura del XML que vas a validar y quítale los punsos suspensivos que puse para indicar que seguro vas a añadir más cosas!!!!!!!):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:simpleType name="nombreType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
  <!-- maximo de 40 caracteres -->
  <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
  <xs:maxInclusive value="40"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- Dimensiones -->
<xs:element name="anchura" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="version" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="altura">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<!-- Atributos generales -->
<xs:element name="fondo" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="peso" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Resolucion_de_pantalla"/>
<xs:element name="Processador" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Memoria" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="Precio" type="xs:string"/>

<!-- Elementos complejos -->
<xs:element name="sistema_operativo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="nombre"/>
        <xs:element ref="version"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Dimensiones">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="anchura"/>
        <xs:element ref="altura"/>
        <xs:element ref="fondo"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="phone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="nombre"/>
        <xs:element ref="memoria"/>
        <xs:element ref="sistema_operativo"/>
        <xs:element ref="Dimensiones"/>
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="smartphone">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="phone"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- FIN Elementos complejos -->

</xs:schema>
```

Así, dentro de `smarthphone` habría N `phone`, cada uno con unas características del teléfono. Tienes que completarlo, hay un poco de atributos que no estás usando en ninguna parte. Tampoco se sabe para qué tienes `nombreType`, pues no se usa en ningún lado. Etc.

Comment: creo que no lo he entendido bien, tengo que cambiar el orden?

Comment: Tienes que poner las cosas con la estructura que dices que va a tener.

Comment: tengo 2 veces sistema operativo porque tengo 2 telefonos (phone) y tengo 1 vez smartphone porque equivale a todo

Comment: No has entendido. **EN EL XSD**, dentro del elemento phone está requerido sistema_operativo, dentro de smartphone también está requerido PERO que esté dentro de phone ES DIFERENTE a que esté dentro de smartphone, son niveles diferentes. Tú puedes tener N elementos phone, pero la forma como los defines en el XSD (smartphone y phone) no corresponde a lo que intentas hacer. Los elementos complejos o simples que definas en el XSD representan relaciones entre ellos y cuántos elementos de cada uno hay, eso lo defines con `minOccurs` y `maxOccurs` y eso no lo estás usando.

Comment: Edité la respuesta, a ver si se entiende mejor. PD. Si la respuesta no te ha servido, bien podrías aclarar las dudas _y cuando te sirva_ la marcas como aceptada. La idea es que eso represente el que _te resolvió tu problema_